# Samsung Printer installation

Tags: printing

I downloaded Samsung printer file but I don't know how to install samsunginstaller.tar.gz by using GUI interface please guide me.

Comment: Probably you won't be able to use any "GUI Interface" (FYI, a pleonasm). The first thing to do is extract that file which should result in a directory and inside it try to find a "readme" or similar with instructions. Then edit your question pointing out the steps you were unable to perform, if any.

Comment: Just in case you run the install.sh and get the printer installed, but it does not work - you need to enter the cups configuration http://localhost:631 and add it again - for some reason the installer adds it, but id does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this to work on Ubuntu 16.04 with Cinnamon Desktop.  I was installing a Samsung ML-2850D attached to a network print server (port L1).

The universal printer driver I downloaded was from Samsung at: http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/ML-2850D/XEU

On that page under "Useful Software" there is a "Samsung Printer Software Installer" with pictures of a user friendly, gui-based, all-in-one installation wizard, but if you select download from an Ubuntu PC you will get a tar file that contains a bash script installation of the driver with no README or explanation.  So I share your pain.

I sudo executed the "install.sh" script in my home directory using the terminal interface.  When asked, I opted to allow it to "automatically" configure my firewall (no idea), and the script completed successfully.  I discovered that the script does not actually install the printer.  It may do something firewall-ish, who knows, but it does put a load of PPD files in /opt/samsung/printer/share/ppd/ directory with names in the format: Samsung[whatever-model-series].ppd.  So pretty easy to figure the one you want.

You can then use Cinnamon's print utility (or I imagine Unity or Gnome, etc) to add your printer.  I added a new Network Printer.  Selected LPD/LPR Host or Printer. Under host put in the LAN IP address and under Queue put (in my case) L1.

On the next screen I indicated that I would supply the PPD file and then browse navigated to the /opt/samsung/.... file with the appropriate name.

This worked for me, and I can even control the printer through a browser with http://localhost:631/printers/ .

You might wish to install the Samsung SmartPanel also.  It is a GUI Applet thing that has printer controls and a link to order supplies and such.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably there will not be a graphical process of installing the drivers.
The file that you mentioned is an archive. You need to extract from it the contents (in GUI or in CLI). 
In most of the cases in the files extracted will exist a file called `install.sh` that you will need to execute. For this you will need to:

- open a terminal
- navigate to the directory where you have extracted the archive
- execute `sudo ./install.sh`
- follow the install process and answer the questions according to you needs

At the end the printer should be directly available.
If not you can try to add it manually from GUI or from CUPS. CUPS is the printing server and you can access it by writing `http://localhost:631` in your browser.

Good luck!